# Add headers h1, h2, h3 (Contempo)

Tags: blogger, personalization

Help I need to implement header H1, H2 and H3 correctly in blogspot theme "Contempo", issue just released a week ago, approx. March 20, 2017. ([Tema contempo](http://herethere-blog.blogspot.pe/))

By default comes H3 for the title of the post

```
<h3 class='post-title entry-title'>
   <b:if cond='data:post.link or (data:post.url and data:view.url != data:post.url)'>
      <a expr:href='data:post.link ?: data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
   <b:else/>
      <data:post.title/>
   </b:if>
</h3>
```

And I need for better SEO to implement

H1 title of article
H2 internal subtitle of the article
H3 subtitle of article

I have implemented this code

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
   <h2 class='post-title entry-title'>
     <b:if cond='data:post.link or (data:post.url and data:view.url != data:post.url)'>
       <a expr:href='data:post.link ?: data:post.url'><data:post.title/></a>
     <b:else/>
       <data:post.title/>
     </b:if>
   </h2>
<b:else/>
   <h1 class='post-title entry-title'><data:post.title/></h1>   
</b:if>
```

But I get:
H1 blog name
H1 article name

And I think there should not be 2 H1 in the home, so something is poorly implemented

Another thing the Contempo theme brings a prominent entry and this is shown in the home as H3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that the page should not contain two h1 elements.

Go to Header1 widget in your template and replace this:

```
<b:include name='super.title'/>
```

With:

```
<b:if cond='data:view.isSingleItem'>
  <h2 class='title'>
    <a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>
      <data:title/>
    </a>
  </h2>
<b:else/>
  <h1 class='title'>
    <a expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>
      <data:title/>
    </a>
  </h1>
</b:if>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help I worked as I wanted it, although the title of the blog changed the color of the links and put the title left.

Your help is very great, I have asked everywhere and at last it could be done. Thanks Bassam

Comment: Thanks Bassam, but unfortunately of css code I do not know anything. I'll mark it as fixed. Also I am putting in the forums that ask this url, so that others can solve the same problem of headings h1, h2 and h3 of blogger 2017.

Comment: The new code is what it does, because I see it the same

Comment: Not the same, I put link after h1,h2 in the new code.

Comment: Thanks for your help