# How to hide title under logo

Tags: blogger

[Add headers h1, h2, h3 (Contempo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148424/add-headers-h1-h2-h3-contempo?answertab=votes#tab-top)
it is work good but when I put my logo  I dont't whant see the title text of my blog.

Answer (score 0):

From your blog dashboard, go to **Layout** > **Header** and select **Instead of title and description**

Comment: Thak you for your answer Bassam. This is done but when I put the code from the link above the title of my blog appeared in the articles. I have no problem with the first page.

Comment: Can you see answer 3 above please.

Answer (score 0):

The Blogger Theme is Contempo, I was able to hide the title by replacing this code:

```
<b:class cond='data:this.imagePlacement == &quot;REPLACE&quot;' name='replaced'/>
```

with this one:

```
<b:class cond='data:this.imagePlacement == &quot;REPLACE&quot;' name='hidden'/>
```

but I'm not sure it's right and it's good for SEO what do you think?

There is two code

```
<b:class cond='data:this.imagePlacement == &quot;REPLACE&quot;' name='replaced'/>
```

I'm changin the second.

Comment: I think there's no problem [read this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/how-bad-is-it-to-use-display-none-in-css)

Comment: Thak you, Is there a better way to hide the headline in articles with another code? There is a little problem when adding second tittle with h2 tag?

Comment: Of course, you can target only headline in header by this CSS rule `header h2 { display: none }`  or share your blog url to define one.

Comment: Ok, to hide blog title in articles, add this to CSS code `.replaced h2 { display: none }`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for help Bassam, I have added this code

```
.centered-top-container .Header .replaced h2, .centered-top-placeholder .Header .replaced h2 {
    display:none;
}
.centered-top-container.sticky .Header .replaced h2 {
    display:block;
}
```

Under this one

```
.centered-top-container .Header .replaced h1, .centered-top-placeholder .Header .replaced h1 {
    display:none;
 }
 .centered-top-container.sticky .Header .replaced h1 {
    display:block;
 }
```

Now everythink is OK, thank you one more time :)